# Adding Bolts Framework to Custom Swift Framework Error

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, frameworks, bolts-framework

I'm trying to create a custom Swift Framework. Within that Framework I've added the Bolts Framework. When trying to use my new Swift Framework in another projects, I get the following error:

framework not found Bolts for architecture x86_64
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Interesting part is that other Frameworks included (Parse) load fine, its just Bolts that is having the issue. I've tried changing the Build Active Architectures settings already.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe your problem is that Parse framework already includes the Bolts framework. You shouldn't need to add it specifically if you're also using Parse.

Comment: Actually Bolts is an additional requirement for Parse

Comment: In my project, using Bolts, I do not include Bolts in my podfile. It is automatically installed with Parse. You're maybe not using cocoapods? If not, then you should :-)

Comment: Did a clean install using cocoapods, everything working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CocoaPods for including your other frameworks. Bolts will then be automatically installed through Parse.

Comment: So I was able to build the app I imported my new framework in with no problems. But actually running the app is giving me a Library not loaded: @rpath/Bolts.framework/Bolts
  Referenced from: /Users/.....   Reason: image not found. Any ideas?

Comment: Check if any of these help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29485035/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-alamofire-framework-versions-a-alamofire-reason 
or 
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3661

Answer (score 0):

Create new Copy Files Phase by going to:

Project Settings -> Build Phases -> `+` -> New Copy Files Phase. Expand the Copy Files Phase and set destination to Frameworks. Then click on the little `+` icon and select `Bolts` framework. Also add it to the linked frameworks and libraries if its not added.

[image: Copy Files]

The error you are experiencing is thrown when the framework you use is not in the Frameworks folder that your app uses.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Are you using prebuilt `Bolts` framework or did you built it?