# Library not loaded: @rpath/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises iOS 13.3.1

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, ios13.3

My app crashes on lunch and getting this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/11X3EC15-5A16-4E27-AC4A-FB0503E6F1E2/Zeta.app/Zeta
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/11X3EC15-5A16-4E27-AC4A-FB0503E6F1E2/Zeta.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/11X3EC15-5A16-4E27-AC4A-FB0503E6F1E2/Zeta.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/11X3EC15-5A16-4E27-AC4A-FB0503E6F1E2/Zeta.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises: stat() failed with errno=25
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/11X3EC15-5A16-4E27-AC4A-FB0503E6F1E2/Zeta.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/11X3EC15-5A16-4E27-AC4A-FB0503E6F1E2/Zeta.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/11X3EC15-5A16-4E27-AC4A-FB0503E6F1E2/Zeta.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises: stat() failed with errno=1
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/11X3EC15-5A16-4E27-AC4A-FB0503E6F1E2/Zeta.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/11X3EC15-5A16-4E27-AC4A-FB0503E6F1E2/Zeta.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/11X3EC15-5A16-4E27-AC4A-FB0503E6F1E2/Zeta.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises: stat() failed with errno=1
(lldb)
```

I used it on my own device (iPhone 11 pro) **iOS 13.3.1**.
It was working perfectly fine before I update my device to iOS 13.3.1 .
My app also works perfectly fine on the simulator (iPhone 11 - iOS 13.3).
Using **Xcode 11.3.1**.

Removing the profile from my device and trusting again didn't work.

**UPDATE:** Tried to build it using **Xcode Beta 11.4** and didn't work.

**UPDATE II:**

- The only pods that I'm using are `Firebase/Auth, Firebase/Core, Firebase/Firestore`.
- Commenting `use_frameworks!` and using `use_modular_headers!` gave me these errors: `Showing Recent Issues The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 4.3, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.2.99.` (For all the pods in the project)

Comment: maybe try to do `pod update` and check if it helps.

Comment: @MaciejGad also tried that. didn't work

Comment: I had the same issue, take at look at [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60045282/after-updating-ios-all-applications-using-the-framework-stopped-running-on-the), it helped me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After updating iOS, all applications using the framework stopped running on the device, but they run on the simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60045282/after-updating-ios-all-applications-using-the-framework-stopped-running-on-the)

Comment: I tried Xcode 11.4 release and it didn't work

Comment: @Roberto upgrade to iOS 13.4 or try a developer account with an active subscription.

Comment: I was getting the same dyld error for GoogleUtilities.framework when running in Simulator. It was caused by CylancePROTECT antivirus software running on my MacBook which blocked execution of the framework. Curiously, I had no problems running on my device.

Comment: xcode: 11.3.1 ios:13.3. Am getting the same error. My developer account is actively subscribed. Worked the first build, i copied the folder and changed the bundle identifier. Then started this issue.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You are probably using free developer account. Apple blocked utilizing external frameworks on free accounts with 13.3.1 upgrade. Try downgrading to 13.3 if still possible or buy Apple Developer License.

UPDATE 04/2020: Upgrading to iOS 13.4 and XCode 11.4 currently solves this issue.

Comment: I've also tried with an account which is in apple developer program but still getting same thing.

Comment: @arata check that you've selected correct Team identifier for code signing.

Comment: "Apple blocked utilizing external frameworks on free accounts"
But.. WHY?!?

Comment: Though this seems to be the case, there's no hard evidence to corroborate it. It may also be a bug in this iOS version. Is there an official announcement on behalf of Apple regarding this (link)?

Comment: Not working for me, iOS 13.4beta4 / iPhone XR

Comment: My account is an enterprise account paid for by my company, and I'm getting this same kind of error.

Comment: I have tried to downgrade to iOS 13.0 and with a paid apple dev account and still same error.

Comment: Unbelievable this as accepted answer. I have try to use my company enterprise acc, still face the same issue.

Comment: xcode: 11.3.1 ios:13.3. Am getting the same error. My developer account is actively subscribed. Worked the first build, i copied the folder and changed the bundle identifier. Then started this issue. Any solutons @TommyLeong

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem after updating my iPhone to iOS 13.3.1.
The fix that has worked for me:
In the Podfile remove `use_frameworks!` and add `,:modular_headers => true` after each pod.
Close xcode, update pods and rebuild.

My full Podfile looks like this:

```
target 'HeatingClient' do
  # use_frameworks!

  pod 'RxSwift',:modular_headers => true
  pod 'RxCocoa',:modular_headers => true

end
```

Comment: If anyone is experiencing this on iOS 14 for App Clips. This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

This issue is specific to **iOS 13.3.1** devices with free dev account, i was struggling with it for 4 days and got the solution.

1. Uninstall Pods from your project folder, use terminal:

   `sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate cocoapods-clean
    pod deintegrate
    pod clean
    rm Podfile`
2. Initialize pods again in project, terminal:
   `pod init`
3. In Podfile change this line:

   ```
   target 'exampleproject' do
     # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
       use_frameworks!
   ```

   to this lines:

   ```
   target 'exampleproject' do
     # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
     # use_frameworks!
     use_modular_headers!
   ```
4. Install Pods again in terminal:
   `pod install`
5. Open project by file .xcworkspace and do `Product > Clean Build Folder`
   (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>)
6. Run and build with free developer account on your **iOS 13.3.1** device.

Comment: using  `use_modular_headers!` gave me these errors `Showing Recent Issues The iOS deployment target  IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET is set to 4.3, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.2.99` for all the pods and also why bother when you can make a clean project again for more accurate results?

Comment: I think you have to change iOS Deployment Target to iOS > 8.0 in Project Setting in Info Tab

Comment: thank you, only your steps helped me. Before it saw the framework but didn't see the classes

Comment: this doesnt work if you have the firebase pod installed, something about swift requiring frameworks to get boringssl working (my error was: module map file '/Users/me/Desktop/myApp/Pods/Headers/Private/openssl_grpc/BoringSSL-GRPC-library.modulemap' not found)

Comment: This worked for me, save my life!

Answer (score 6):

As was mentioned above:

> Apple blocked utilizing external frameworks on free accounts with
>   13.3.1 upgrade.

So use developer account with active subscription or use static libraries.

[Solution for Cocoapods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60059840/1135154) - use `use_modular_headers!`

Comment: I'm using a developer account now but also getting the same problem and even when I use `use_modular_headers` I'm getting `Showing Recent Issues The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 4.3, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.2.99.` for all the pods and I only added the Firebase pods (Firestore, Core, Auth). I've re-made my app with both Xcode 11.3.1 and 11.4 Beta.

Comment: @arata well, error message says that you've set ios 4.3 somewhere. Minimal is 8.0. If it is related to pods add `platform :ios, '8.0'` to Podfile or [post script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58367269/1135154). otherwise look to your targets. Also if you use dev account you can still use `use_frameworks!` instead of `use_modular_headers!`

Comment: use_modular_headers! works for me!!!

Comment: It looks like they are preparing to push for Swift Package Manager (it will support resources from Swift 6) and kill CocoaPods.

Answer (score 4):

I was using apple free account, switched to apple paid account and it worked in iOS 13.3.1

Comment: did you try to re-install the profile to see if it's working again or not?

Comment: @arata, yes its working for paid account only...

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a non-developer Apple ID to install the app on your phone? It looks like iOS 13.3.1 has broken apps installed with free Apple IDs, but only if they contain embedded frameworks. If it's possible to link all your dependencies as static libraries rather than frameworks (for example, if you're using Cocoapods you can remove use_frameworks! from your Podfile), that should fix the issue for now.

Answer (score 2):

the issue is with iOS 13.3.1 and free developer accounts . the issue is fixed on latest iOS 13.4 beta I confirm it.
for now you can use

> use_modular_headers!

instead of

> use_frameworks!

in project Podfile

Comment: Indeed, you are correct. A combination of Xcode 11.4 beta 2 and iOS 13.4 beta 4 solves the issue.

Comment: Can confirm that Xcode 11.4 and iOS 13.4 combination solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

Looks like whe only way to avoid error on free account is use ios 13.3, because even in iOS 13.4 beta apple didn't fix it.
Using `use_modular_headers!` is not working for Firebase.

Comment: Firebase is treating this as an iOS issue and does not plan to release a fix. Let's hope iOS 13.3.2 fixes the issue. No news from Apple so far.

Comment: It helped for me https://take.ms/JMf9h and podfile , but I had to follow MarcoPolokk's steps

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem on the Xcode or the framework itself, I was got the same error on Xcode 11.4 beta and iOS 13.4 beta 1. Use the Xcode 11.3.1 for running on real devices until the next beta of Xcode will be released.

Comment: I have used both Xcode 11.3.1 and Xcode 11.4 Beta. getting same results

Answer (score 0):

Open the file extension and make sure it's in the library.

> Open Xcode -> Products -> YourApp.app -> "Show in Finder"

And you see

> "YourApp.app" -> This file "right click" and click -> "Show package
>   contents"

If libraries are missing here, you need to check their framework connections.

Answer (score 0):

I tried commenting out the line  # use_frameworks! in the pod file and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem. power of `use_modular_headers!` to avoid the crash and below code working for me.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
#platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'YourApp' do

   use_modular_headers!
  # Pods for YourApp

   pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 5.0'
   pod 'GoogleMaps'
   pod 'GooglePlaces'
   pod 'Firebase/Analytics'

end
```