# Application crash when calling method 'FirebaseApp.configure()' in a real device

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crash, appdelegate

Recently, I decided to run the application on a real device and received a crash application and, looking for the reason, I found that it appears after the FirebaseApp.configure() method.

The application does not crash when launched in the simulator.

Crash:

```
dyld`__abort_with_payload:
    0x101b0b2a4 <+0>:  mov    x16, #0x209
    0x101b0b2a8 <+4>:  svc    #0x80
->  0x101b0b2ac <+8>:  b.lo   0x101b0b2c8               ; <+36>
    0x101b0b2b0 <+12>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x101b0b2b4 <+16>: mov    x29, sp
    0x101b0b2b8 <+20>: bl     0x101b097d8               ; cerror_nocancel
    0x101b0b2bc <+24>: mov    sp, x29
    0x101b0b2c0 <+28>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp], #0x10
    0x101b0b2c4 <+32>: ret    
    0x101b0b2c8 <+36>: ret
```

With this backtrace:

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
  * frame #0: 0x0000000101b0b2ac dyld`__abort_with_payload + 8
    frame #1: 0x0000000101b12914 dyld`abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 104
    frame #2: 0x0000000101b12948 dyld`abort_with_payload + 16
    frame #3: 0x0000000101b0f77c dyld`dyld::halt(char const*) + 380
    frame #4: 0x0000000101ac0778 dyld`dyld::fastBindLazySymbol(ImageLoader**, unsigned long) + 176
    frame #5: 0x00000001b207963c libdyld.dylib`_dyld_fast_stub_entry(void*, long) + 80
    frame #6: 0x00000001b2077b80 libdyld.dylib`dyld_stub_binder + 60
    frame #7: 0x0000000100b88258 CheeseApp`__44+[UIViewController(APMScreenClassName) load]_block_invoke + 144
    frame #8: 0x000000010204327c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 20
    frame #9: 0x0000000102044c88 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_once_callout + 132
    frame #10: 0x0000000100b881c4 CheeseApp`+[UIViewController(APMScreenClassName) load] + 76
    frame #11: 0x00000001b1fa1500 libobjc.A.dylib`load_images + 1176
    frame #12: 0x0000000101abe19c dyld`dyld::notifySingle(dyld_image_states, ImageLoader const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList*) + 480
    frame #13: 0x0000000101ace444 dyld`ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 556
    frame #14: 0x0000000101acd094 dyld`ImageLoader::processInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 192
    frame #15: 0x0000000101acd160 dyld`ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 96
    frame #16: 0x0000000101abe4f8 dyld`dyld::initializeMainExecutable() + 220
    frame #17: 0x0000000101ac3038 dyld`dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) + 4668
    frame #18: 0x0000000101abd22c dyld`dyldbootstrap::start(dyld3::MachOLoaded const*, int, char const**, dyld3::MachOLoaded const*, unsigned long*) + 432
    frame #19: 0x0000000101abd038 dyld`_dyld_start + 56
```

AppDelegate:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }
}
```

What I tried:

1. I updated the GoogleService-Info.plist file in the root directory
2. I updated all libraries in pod file
3. I tried to solve the problem by disabling the Address Sanitizer in scheme
4. I tried to add .plist file via "Add Files to..."
5. I tried to run the method like this:

```
    override init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
```

6. I updated library in 'Linked Binary With Libraries'

But nothing helped.

Comment: What's the backtrace?

Comment: @PaulBeusterien bt: https://codeshare.io/214A17

Comment: Maybe related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60096258/library-not-loaded-rpath-fblpromises-framework-fblpromises-ios-13-3-1/60101963#60101963

Comment: @PaulBeusterien Thanks for the help! It worked, please write your comment as an answer so that I can choose it as a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is another symptom of Apple blocking free developer accounts from using dynamic frameworks starting with iOS 13.3.1.

Options include
 - Upgrade to paid developer account
 - Downgrade to 13.3.
 - With CocoaPods, use `use_modular_headers!` instead of `use_frameworks!`

See also [Library not loaded: @rpath/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises iOS 13.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60096258/library-not-loaded-rpath-fblpromises-framework-fblpromises-ios-13-3-1/60101963#60101963)

Comment: Wow, just wow. Pulling my hair out until I found this. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to library image not loaded in release build. See if library is checked in 'Linked Binary With Libraries' section in your 'Build Phases'.

Comment: The library image was uploaded before, but nothing helped: https://ibb.co/VMPMWRJ