# How Do I ' #import "Firebase.h ' in Xcode?

Tags: swift, firebase, sdk, cocoapods

I'm manually adding some Firebase SDK's in my iOS app and have been following Firebase's provided [readme](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/ZipBuilder/Template/README.md) to the letter. As it directs, I've already dragged all the SDKs I need into my project but there's one step I'm not understanding. It reads:

**8. Drag the `Firebase.h` header in this directory into your project. This will
   allow you to `#import "Firebase.h"` and start using any Firebase SDKs that you
   have.**

I've added the `Firebase.h` header file into my project but I don't know how/where to add `#import "Firebase.h"`. Since I haven't done that, building my app produces the error: `No such module 'Firebase'` when I try to `import Firebase` in my view controllers.

For reference, I had been using cocoapods for Firebase up until the recent iOS 13.3.1 update that broke my ability to test my app on my physical device, so I'm attempting to manually add the static Firebase SDK's in the hopes that I would then be able to continue debugging on my iPhone 6s. I'm 75% of the way through my app's development and have already fully integrated Firebase so this little switch-over from pods to static SDKs is definitely annoying, but it has to be done. I removed all the Firebase pods I was using in my Podfile and am just stuck at the step bolded above... hopefully it's a simple thing and then everything will work again as I already have it completely integrated throughout my app.

If you'd like a deeper background, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60096258/library-not-loaded-rpath-fblpromises-framework-fblpromises-ios-13-3-1) a Stack Overflow question that describes the exact initial problem I was having with debugging on my physical device with the 13.3.1 iOS update.

And [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60269706/is-there-an-alternative-way-to-incorporate-firebase-into-my-ios-app-other-than-c/60272840?noredirect=1#comment106649206_60272840) where I asked for alternative ways to incorporate Firebase that avoids pods (in case that fixes the issue). This is where I learned about Firebase's [zip binary distribution](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#frameworks). I downloaded the zip file with the Firebase SDKs, chose the ones I need, and have been following the readme to add them to my project.

Answer (score 0):

To add Firebase module support, you also need to do the subsequent instruction in the zip distribution [README](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/ZipBuilder/Template/README.md) after dragging Firebase.h:

```
9. If you're using Swift, or you want to use modules, drag module.modulemap into
   your project and update your User Header Search Paths to contain the
   directory that contains your module map.
```

Comment: I had also dragged the module.modulemap into my project, but I likely haven't updated my User Header Search Paths correctly then. One thing I tried was navigating to the module.modulemap in my project directory, right clicked on it and selected "get info" to copy the 'where' directory of the file. That's what I pasted into my User Header Search Paths. I'm assuming it needs to be in a certain format though... what might that be? If I can get this working tonight, I'll mark your answer as correct both here and on my other linked question.