# Swift 5, iOS 13.3.1 FBSDKCoreKit error (Derived Data deletion doesn't help)

Tags: facebook, swift4, fbsdk

Have updated `sudo gem install cocoapods --pre`, `iOS 13.3.1` on my `iPhone 7`, and `Podfile`.
After that `FBSDKCoreKit` error has appeared.

[image] 
[image]

```
Thread 1 (0 __abort_with_payload):
    dyld`__abort_with_payload:
        0x10251f5dc <+0>:  mov    x16, #0x209
        0x10251f5e0 <+4>:  svc    #0x80
    ->  0x10251f5e4 <+8>:  b.lo   0x10251f600               ; <+36>
        0x10251f5e8 <+12>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
        0x10251f5ec <+16>: mov    x29, sp
        0x10251f5f0 <+20>: bl     0x10251dbe8               ; cerror_nocancel
        0x10251f5f4 <+24>: mov    sp, x29
        0x10251f5f8 <+28>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp], #0x10
        0x10251f5fc <+32>: ret    
        0x10251f600 <+36>: ret
```

Console:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/8A12DD33-F4BE-41BA-97AF-B6B112E40362/112:UA.app/112:UA
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/8A12DD33-F4BE-41BA-97AF-B6B112E40362/112:UA.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/8A12DD33-F4BE-41BA-97AF-B6B112E40362/112:UA.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/8A12DD33-F4BE-41BA-97AF-B6B112E40362/112:UA.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/8A12DD33-F4BE-41BA-97AF-B6B112E40362/112:UA.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/8A12DD33-F4BE-41BA-97AF-B6B112E40362/112:UA.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit: stat() failed with errno=1
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/8A12DD33-F4BE-41BA-97AF-B6B112E40362/112:UA.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/8A12DD33-F4BE-41BA-97AF-B6B112E40362/112:UA.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/8A12DD33-F4BE-41BA-97AF-B6B112E40362/112:UA.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit: stat() failed with errno=1
(lldb)
```

To make this faster:

- Already tried to clean the build folder, derived data;
- Cleaned Pods and all pods references;
- Tried to launch previous versions of the project;
- Tried to install an exactly previous version of FacebookSDK.

All work if I launch the application on previous iOS firmware. iPhone 6/7/8 goes well it's firmware is below 13.3.1.

Deprecated methods for FacebookSDK? If there is no update for this framework, what's next?

Answer (score 1):

apple blocked load external library for free account from 13.3.1

use use_modular_headers! instead of useframework

[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60211703/10199138)

Comment: target 'project_name' do
use_modular_headers!
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

Changed the Pod file. Didn't work. "ld: framework not found FBSDKCoreKit"