# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises in XCode 11.3.1

Tags: ios, flutter

Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/03C7127E-F14D-44C0-8EF9-527AC6FDFCDF/Runner.app/Runner
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/03C7127E-F14D-44C0-8EF9-527AC6FDFCDF/Runner.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/03C7127E-F14D-44C0-8EF9-527AC6FDFCDF/Runner.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises'

/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/03C7127E-F14D-44C0-8EF9-527AC6FDFCDF/Runner.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises: stat() failed with errno=1
(lldb)

Comment: hi. can you provide details on how you encounter this problem or what you did that led you to this issue?

Comment: Hello, I'm trying to run my flutter code on iOS using XCode. the application was succesfully build on iOS Simulator. But, when i'm trying to install it on my device, i'm receiving this error and my app is stopped on splash screen

Comment: i saw an invalid code signature as above. did you add and register your ios device through `App Store Connect`? can you check to see if it is still valid?

Answer (score 2):

Try my solution to that problem, nothing was working until I got it like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60394826/12589334