# Why Apple blocked utilising external frameworks on free accounts on iOS 13.3.1?

Tags: ios, apple-developer

Recently I was working on project using apple account with no active subscription (free developer account) which contained the firebase pods only and after upgrading my device to iOS 13.3.1 my app started crashing with this reason:

[**Library not loaded: @rpath/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60096258/library-not-loaded-rpath-fblpromises-framework-fblpromises-ios-13-3-1)

and I found out that:

> Apple blocked utilising external frameworks on free accounts with 13.3.1 upgrade.

so I used an apple developer account with an active subscription and the problem solved.

**But Why Apple blocked utilising external frameworks?**

Comment: You would have to ask them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Apple wants to force Free Account using `Swift Package` .

Anyway you can use pods by making this workaround 
 - remove or comment this line `use_frameworks!` in Podfile
 - reinstall your pods `pod install`

The build will be succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

As a follow on to Mohammed Elnaggar's answer, if you need modules because you're using Swift or module imports in Objective-C:

Replace `use_frameworks!` with `use_modular_headers!`