# Xcode 11: App crashes on start after 'pod install' with dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, xcode11

I recently installed some pods into my iOS app (Firebase pods). The app was running fine but immediately after the 'pod install' the app crashes with the error message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises
Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/82B650FF-B055-4D1C-9F24-7D37CD52351E/{app-name}.app/{app-name}
Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/82B650FF-B055-4D1C-9F24-7D37CD52351E/{app-name}.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/82B650FF-B055-4D1C-9F24-7D37CD52351E/{app-name}.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises'
```

I tried to set *Embed & Sign* in **Project file > General > Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content** but that causes a compile error. Currently the libraries are set to *Do not embed*.

I also tried to create an entire new project and install the pods in that project but that causes the same error. Removing the pods from the project removes the error.

Uninstalling the app on the device, cleaning the build folder and rebuilding also did not solve the problem

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: `Apple blocked utilising external frameworks on free accounts with 13.3.1 upgrade.` Try to check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60096258/library-not-loaded-rpath-fblpromises-framework-fblpromises-ios-13-3-1 and https://github.com/google/promises/issues/126

Comment: for the solution and more details [check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60395827/10739162)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Apple blocked utilising external frameworks on free accounts on iOS 13.3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60394268/why-apple-blocked-utilising-external-frameworks-on-free-accounts-on-ios-13-3-1)