# pod framework not loading in ios 13.3.1

Tags: ios, swift

> > My project is working perfectly fine on Simulator but the moment I am installing on Device I am getting following issues.

```
dyld: Library not loaded:
```

Following point to consider while digging into issue
Membership: Using free account to install project in device.
iOS Version: 13.3.1
Use any pod library

Looks like this problem in only with 13.1.1. Can some one check with other iOS Version.

Steps:

```
 1. Create New project
 2: Add any pod 
 3: install pod 
 4: Run on Device 

Complete Error: dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/MDFInternationalization.framework/MDFInternationalization

  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1DFBADF5-AB1A-4400-90E7-B1AA35CAE4A5/TestProjectForDynamicViews.app/TestProjectForDynamicViews

  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1DFBADF5-AB1A-4400-90E7-B1AA35CAE4A5/TestProjectForDynamicViews.app/Frameworks/MDFInternationalization.framework/MDFInternationalization: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1DFBADF5-AB1A-4400-90E7-B1AA35CAE4A5/TestProjectForDynamicViews.app/Frameworks/MDFInternationalization.framework/MDFInternationalization'



    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1DFBADF5-AB1A-4400-90E7-B1AA35CAE4A5/TestProjectForDynamicViews.app/Frameworks/MDFInternationalization.framework/MDFInternationalization: stat() failed with errno=25

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1DFBADF5-AB1A-4400-90E7-B1AA35CAE4A5/TestProjectForDynamicViews.app/Frameworks/MDFInternationalization.framework/MDFInternationalization: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1DFBADF5-AB1A-4400-90E7-B1AA35CAE4A5/TestProjectForDynamicViews.app/Frameworks/MDFInternationalization.framework/MDFInternationalization'



    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1DFBADF5-AB1A-4400-90E7-B1AA35CAE4A5/TestProjectForDynamicViews.app/Frameworks/MDFInternationalization.framework/MDFInternationalization: stat() failed with errno=1

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1DFBADF5-AB1A-4400-90E7-B1AA35CAE4A5/TestProjectForDynamicViews.app/Frameworks/MDFInternationalization.framework/MDFInternationalization: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1DFBADF5-AB1A-4400-90E7-B1AA35CAE4A5/TestProjectForDynamicViews.app/Frameworks/MDFInternationalization.framework/MDFInternationalization'



    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1DFBADF5-AB1A-4400-90E7-B1AA35CAE4A5/TestProjectForDynamicViews.app/Frameworks/MDFInternationalization.framework/MDFInternationalization: stat() failed with errno=1
```

Answer (score 1):

i got the same error and peoples are suggesting that doing these steps and it works:

- remove/comment `use_frameworks!` in Podfile
- add `use_modular_headers!` in Podfile
- pod update
- pod install
- clean and run

solves the issue with using free Apple ID on iOS 13.3.X

from :- [App runs perfectly on simulators but not on physical devices [on iOS 13.3.1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60014739/app-runs-perfectly-on-simulators-but-not-on-physical-devices-on-ios-13-3-1/60055001#60055001)

Answer (score 0):

This is a new update from Apple

Check this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60395827/10739162), it would be helpful.