# App crashes when I run it on physical device using cocoa pods

Tags: swift, cocoapods

Today I decided that I wanted to test my app on a physical device. I don't know what is going on but my app keep crashing when I try to run it. This is what I am getting every time I am trying to run my app.

***dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/GoogleUtilities.framework/GoogleUtilities
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5E49DB3F-CF09-4E3C-BEE6-9A0EE8A332D5/Firebase Realtime Database Test.app/Firebase Realtime Database Test
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5E49DB3F-CF09-4E3C-BEE6-9A0EE8A332D5/Firebase Realtime Database Test.app/Frameworks/GoogleUtilities.framework/GoogleUtilities: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5E49DB3F-CF09-4E3C-BEE6-9A0EE8A332D5/Firebase Realtime Database Test.app/Frameworks/GoogleUtilities.framework/GoogleUtilities'***

So I am using firebase in my app. The thing is it works on the simulator but it doesn't work on an actual iPhone device. I deleted my Podfile for my project like this.

[image]

I ran it without the pods and it didn't crash. Now I reinstall all the pods and tried again but it still crashes my app. Now would I need to uninstall cocoa pods completely from my computer and reinstall it again?

I will try and see what happens if I uninstall cocoa pods and reinstall. Until then would someone please help me figure out why this is happening.

Comment: Likely a variation of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60096258/library-not-loaded-rpath-fblpromises-framework-fblpromises-ios-13-3-1

Comment: @PaulBeusterien, Thanks for the link you provided. It help me solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

So the problem is that apple doesn't allow free developer account to use third party frameworks, on update 13.3.1. This is what I read on the link that Paul provided. So if you want to use a pod from cocoa pods all you have to do is make ur Podfile look something like this.

[image]

All you have to do is comment use_frameworks! and use use_modular_headers! instead. Now someone said that it doesn't work with firebase. I haven't tried it with firebase so I don't know if it works or it doesn't. It work for me using the 'SDWebImage' pod, now this isn't a permanent fixed. This just allowed me to run the app on my physical phone without crashing. Hope this help others.

**Edit 1**

Just tried using firebase and it work. Uninstall previous pods like I did in my question and reinstall all the pods I was using before. Now I am going to repeat myself. This shouldn't be a permeant fix, this is more of a work around. Some people say you can just downgrade your iOS on your phone but don't know how to do that. So I will be sticking with this for now, until I upgrade my free developer account.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, In the target's General tab, under the `Embedded Binaries` field add the `Firebase` framework to resolve the crash

[image]

Comment: thanks for trying to help. It turns out the problem was Apple, LOL. The link that Paul provided solved my problem.