# AdMob for iOS missing frameworks errors

Tags: ios, admob, cocoapods

I followed the instructions in https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start (I've tried twice already), but when I run my app it crashes. It seems like it can't find the `FBLPromises.framework`. In the project navigator that framework and some other files are in red.

At first, it wouldn't even build, but I found an article that said to set the Pod's script to run on installs only. So now it builds but crashes immediately.

[image: Missing frameworks show in red in the project navigator]

The error I get is this:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises
> Referenced from: /Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9E7DEF6C-2C86-4E3C-82CF-13F2388060B5/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/70DE82B4-0792-4645-9197-07C9CE191D88/myapp.app/My app
> Reason: image not found

My pod file (I removed the info for the tests and a watch extension since I only want ads on the one target):

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '14.0'

target 'My app' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
  # Pods for My app

end
```

I tried commenting out `use_frameworks!` and adding something about headers on the podfile, but it didn't do anything. I also tried changing the pod path on build settings, but also nothing.

I downloaded the framework version for manual download and tried adding the missing framework, but the files seem to have different names, so I couldn't tell which file to put where.

Comment: error doesn't look like realted to admob.. have you tried solutions provided here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60096258/library-not-loaded-rpath-fblpromises-framework-fblpromises-ios-13-3-1

Comment: Yes I tried a few of those but didn’t help. I’ll try them again. I see one I haven’t tried yet. Thanks