# "dyld`__abort_with_payload:” When running app in a device after adding app icons

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I added the App Icons to my projects today and ran it on the simulator, it worked well, but when I ran the project on a device, the device crashed and XCode showed me this error:

[image: Error]

This was what was printed in the debug console, but this was only printed at times, not always:

[image: Debug console]

There were many solutions for this problem but none of them worked for me.

Comment: The solution is to switch code signing profiles. change from one team member to another and run the app on the device.

Comment: @ArashEtemad one team member to another? I’m sorry, I’m super lost here

Comment: See https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4294#issuecomment-342852567, it's the same

Comment: Hey @ArashEtemad, I found a fix for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60045282/after-updating-ios-all-applications-using-the-framework-stopped-running-on-the/60059840#60059840

Comment: @ArashEtemad and thanks for trying to help me out man! :)

Comment: Voting as duplicate: [After updating iOS, all applications using the framework stopped running on the device, but they run on the simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60045282/after-updating-ios-all-applications-using-the-framework-stopped-running-on-the)